# Binding text message with websocket using Netty in browser

Tags: java, netty

I am trying to implement websockets using Netty. I tried DiscardServer example and it works fine if I just run it using Telnet like

```
  Telnet localhost 8090.
```

So whatever the message I put in terminal window it returns me back. But now  I want to implement same in browser like if I put some text message in a text area then it should display that text message on browser.

I can start the websocket server using the following code

```
    ChannelFactory factory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(factory);

    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
            return Channels.pipeline(new DiscardServerHandler());
        }
    });

    bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);

    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8090));
```

but how can I bind my text message in my text area with the websocket server

**----Updated----**

I have created MyServerHandler class

```
   public class MyServerHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    Object msg = e.getMessage();        
    //msg.getClass();
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
                    //handleHttpRequest(ctx, (HttpRequest) msg);
        ctx.getChannel().write(msg);
    } else if (msg instanceof WebSocketFrame) {
        //handleWebSocketFrame(ctx, (WebSocketFrame) msg);
    }

}
  }
```

Its calling messageReceived Method but not going to any of if condition.

I wrote WebSocketServerPipelineFactory class also

```
   public class WebSocketServerPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {

@Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        // Create a default pipeline implementation.
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(65536));
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new MyServerHandler());
        return pipeline;
    }
    }
```

I thing its not calling method of this class also.

In jsp file I have written

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
   var MESSAGE_HANDSHAKE = "handshake";
   var MESSAGE_OPPONENT_UPDATE = "response";
   var MESSAGE_TURN_INDICATOR = "turn";
   var MESSAGE_GAME_OVER = "game_over";
   var WEBSOCKET_URL = "ws://localhost:8090";
   $(document).ready(function() {
   ws = new WebSocket(WEBSOCKET_URL);

   ws.onopen = function(event) { 
 alert("test");
 $('#status').text("Waiting...."); 
  };

   ws.onmessage = function(event) {
    var message = jQuery.parseJSON(event.data);

    alert(message.type);
   }

   }); 

<body>
 <p id="status">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
```

Its not going to any of jquery methods. Am I still missing something?

Also, If I write

```
  ws.send("Test Message");
```

it throws following java script error

```
 Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 login.htm:33
 (anonymous function) login.htm:33
 f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWith jquery.min.js:2
 e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
 c.addEventListener.C
```

If I use

```
   var WEBSOCKET_URL = "wss://echo.websocket.org/";
```

Then it works so is this that I am not able to connect to my server ?

I am using eclipse to run this code. I am running my jsp code using Apache Tomcat and running websocket server by running WebsocketServer.class as java application. Is that make any difference?

**--- Updated---**

I wrote the following method in MyServerHandler class and getting the error in my browser

```
 Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing
```

MySeverHandler.java

```
  private void handleHttpRequest(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest req)
        throws Exception {

    // Allow only GET methods.
    if (req.getMethod() != HttpMethod.GET) {
    //  sendHttpResponse(ctx, req, new DefaultHttpResponse(
        //      HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.FORBIDDEN));
        return;
    }

    // Serve the WebSocket handshake request.
    if (req.getUri().equals(WEBSOCKET_PATH)
            && Values.UPGRADE.equalsIgnoreCase(req.getHeader(CONNECTION))
            && WEBSOCKET.equalsIgnoreCase(req.getHeader(Names.UPGRADE))) {

        // Create the WebSocket handshake response.
        HttpResponse res = new DefaultHttpResponse(
                HTTP_1_1,
                new HttpResponseStatus(101, "Web Socket Protocol Handshake"));
        res.addHeader(Names.UPGRADE, WEBSOCKET);
        res.addHeader(CONNECTION, Values.UPGRADE);


        // Upgrade the connection and send the handshake response.
        ChannelPipeline p = ctx.getChannel().getPipeline();
        p.remove("aggregator");
        p.replace("decoder", "wsdecoder", new WebSocketFrameDecoder());

        // Write handshake response to the channel
        ctx.getChannel().write(res);

        // Upgrade encoder to WebSocketFrameEncoder
        p.replace("encoder", "wsencoder", new WebSocketFrameEncoder());

        // Initialize the game. Assign players to a game and assign them a letter (X or O)
        ///initGame(ctx);

        return;
    }

    // Send an error page otherwise.
    sendHttpResponse(ctx, req, new DefaultHttpResponse(
            HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.FORBIDDEN));
}
```

Comment: "Its calling messageReceived Method but not going to any of if condition." What is the class of the incoming object then? do a debug or a print statement and check it out. Your best bet to make it work would be look at recent examples in github, web. The tic-tac-toe one is a bit outdated.

Comment: the class name is class org.jboss.netty.buffer.BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer  is this correct?

Comment: How could I find the recent example in github on netty websocket?

Comment: I think your decoder in the pipeline is not setup properly then. Else the class name would be either HTTPRequest or WebSocketFrame. Why dont you put debug points in eclipse and try to see message flow through your decoders to see what exactly is happening. Also take a look at your method call stack and see if the decoders/encoders are getting invoked.

Comment: I have just copy and paste the code you gave me and its the same in github also. I put the breakpoint in WebSocketServerPipelineFactory class but its not going there its just call the messageReceived method where I put the breakpoint. I am really fed-up with this. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think you are not passing this pipeline factory to the server bootstap. Are you passing something else? Definitely this is because pipeline is misconfigured. Check out this link on how to configure your bootstrap http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.html

Comment: Hi Abe , you are write it was a very silly mistake I found it yesterday. Now I am getting invalid version format:: ￀￀￀ Now what is this? Thanks for your patient Abe

Comment: invalid version format is gone when I change the URL from wss:// to ws:// is this correct? Now I am getting error at browser Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing. Anyway I am accepting your answer. But if you could tell me why this error that would be great and I can up vote your comments too :)

Comment: I am not able to understand what to write in MyServerHandles and how it can send the response back to browser.

Comment: Did you take a good look at the tic-tac-toe code in github, it shows how to write back to client. Partial code snippet provided here // Upgrade the connection and send the handshake response.
ChannelPipeline p = ctx.getChannel().getPipeline();
p.remove("aggregator");
p.replace("decoder", "wsdecoder", new WebSocketFrameDecoder());
// Write handshake response to the channel
ctx.getChannel().write(res);

Comment: Hi Abe thanks for your response. Please look at my handleHttpRequest method in updates. I don't get if I still missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netty uses chain of responsibility design pattern, so whenever you need to use  a protocol you need to create appropriate decoders/encoders in your pipeline. For websocket here is an example pipeline.

```
public class WebSocketServerPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            // Create a default pipeline implementation.
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = pipeline();
            pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
            pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(65536));
            pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
            pipeline.addLast("handler", new YourBusinessHandler());
            return pipeline;
    }
```

}

You can write any business logic in your buisness handler. In this case you would just be echoing back what you received so it would be something like `channel.write(incomingMessage);` in this handler.

Take a look at this [tic-tac-toe game](http://kevinwebber.ca/blog/2011/11/2/multiplayer-tic-tac-toe-in-java-using-the-websocket-api-nett.html) for more information. Also there are many links information in github on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Abe, thanks for your response the article seems good but still I am facing some issue can you please check my update.